# jQuery::Scrollable Div does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a scrollable DIV using the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        div.container {
          overflow:hidden;
          width:200px;
          height:200px;
        }
        div.content {
          position:relative;
          top:0;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
          $(".container a.up").bind("click", function(){
            var topVal = $(this).parents(".container").find(".content").css("top");
            $(this).parents(".container").find(".content").css("top", topVal-10);
          });

          $(".container a.dn").bind("click", function(){
            var topVal = $(this).parents(".container").find(".content").css("top");
            $(this).parents(".container").find(".content").css("top", topVal+10);
          });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <p>
    <a href="#" class="up">Up</a> / 
    <a href="#" class="dn">Down</a>
  </p>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Hello World 1</p>
    <p>Hello World 2</p>
    <p>Hello World 3</p>
    <p>Hello World 4</p>
    <p>Hello World 5</p>
    <p>Hello World 6</p>
    <p>Hello World 7</p>
    <p>Hello World 8</p>
    <p>Hello World 9</p>
    <p>Hello World 10</p>
    <p>Hello World 10</p>
    <p>Hello World 11</p>
    <p>Hello World 12</p>
    <p>Hello World 13</p>
    <p>Hello World 14</p>
    <p>Hello World 15</p>
    <p>Hello World 16</p>
    <p>Hello World 17</p>
    <p>Hello World 18</p>
    <p>Hello World 19</p>
    <p>Hello World 20</p>
    <p>Hello World 21</p>
    <p>Hello World 22</p>
    <p>Hello World 23</p>
    <p>Hello World 24</p>
    <p>Hello World 25</p>
    <p>Hello World 26</p>
    <p>Hello World 27</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know where I am messing up, but it simply refuses to work. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I have tried both overflow: auto and overflow: hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`topVal` is a string, like `100px`. You would need to `parseInt(topVal, 10)` to read it before adding a number to it (and that's assuming it was already set to a pixel value).

Better to use [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to change the vertical scrolling position instead of trying to mess with the CSS. Also remember to `return false` from your click handlers to stop the `#` link being followed. Or, better, don't mark the buttons up as links, 'cos they're not links, they don't go anywhere. Use a button or eg. span, styled as appropriate.

Better still to just use a perfectly normal `overflow: auto` div and let the browser provide the scrollbar. This will typically be much more usable than having custom scroll-up/scroll-down buttons, which personally I always find infuriatingly unpleasant to use.

Comment: Agreed - homemade scrolling mechanisms are a terrible idea.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use overflow:auto otherwise the scroll will not show up.

EDIT: I just threw your code into a page and looked at it. This changes my answer a bit. From what I see, do you want to have it scrollable by the Up/Down links?

You should use `$(this).preventDefault()` as well to stop the # from showing up in the URL when you click Up or Down.

This doesn't necessarily solve your curiosity but someone has already developed a plugin that might be useful if you wish to use it.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html

Comment: Yup... I don't want the scrollbars but rather want to control through the links... If I can get that animate effect to work, that would be awesome.

Comment: I had vaguely remembered a plugin when I was trying to find something last week (link is in my answer). It is obviously possible to do what you want to do, I however cannot think of it. But if you don't HAVE to reinvent the wheel, I would use the plugin

Answer (score 0):

why have you used overflow:hidden         try using overflow:auto

div.container { 
          overflow:auto; 
          width:200px; 
          height:200px; 
        }